# Finding out where a complex function is holomorphic and relating this to its expansion as a power series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, uniform-convergence

I am a student whose Complex Analysis' knowledge is gone for a long time. With this in mind, I start by apologizing if my question is too trivial.

Let us consider the complex function

$$ \frac{1}{1 + \sum_{l=1}^n c_l z^l},$$

where $c_l$ are some coefficients and $z$ is our variable. This function is clearly holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $z=0$ and thus it admits an expansion as a power series, i.e., there exists coefficients $a_n$ such that

$$ \frac{1}{1 + \sum_{l=1}^n c_l z^l} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n. $$

Now, my question is: In which domain can we guarantee convergence of this series? I know the follwing is a well-known result in complex analysis:

> If a function $f$ is holomorphic at $D(0,R),$ then there exist coefficients $a_n$ such that
> $$ f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n, \quad \text{ for }|z| < R. $$

So, to determine the domain of convergence of the series I presented above I believe that all one should do is to determine the largest disk centered in $0$ in which our function is holomorphic. I don't know how to do this thought.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: $a_0=1, \quad a_1=f^\prime(0), \quad a_2=f^{\prime \prime}(0)/2!, \quad \cdots.$

Comment: @mjw I know that the coefficients follow from the Taylor series expansion. How does this help calculating the domain of convergence?

Comment: $\displaystyle \frac{1}{R}= \lim \sup |a_n|^{1/n}.$

Comment: @mjw That doesn't sound too sympathic to compute for this specific function... Right?

Comment: Factor the denominator, and find the closest pole of $f$ to the origin.  The distance from this pole to the origin is $R$.

Comment: Your function is holomorphic everywhere, except at the poles, right?

Comment: Yes, that is true @mjw . I don't know the formulas for $c_l$ and thus it might be a hard task to compute the poles of this function. I have a different approach in mind: this exercise came up while solving another exercise (it is just an intermediary step) and it would suffice if I could say something along the lines of the following: " The series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ converges in a sufficiently small nieghbourhood of $z=0$ ". I believe this is true just by looking at the result I highlighted in gray in the post. Is this statement **actually** true?

Comment: Yes that statement is true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $\displaystyle \gamma = \min \left\{ \frac{1}{n \max_{l \in \{1,\cdots,n\}} |c_l| },1\right\},$ so that $\displaystyle \left|\sum_l c_l z^l\right|<1$, for $|z|<\gamma$ and $f(z)$ is holomorphic and thus analytic there.  That is $R$, the radius of convergence for a series centered at zero satisfies $R \ge \gamma.$